# Access violation when static_casting a mid-sized number of T* to void*

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, casting

So I've been goofing around in C++ after taking a bit of a hiatus. I am trying to hack together a dynamic map class that maps a std::string to any object type. According to the C++ standard static_casting a pointer to and from void* preserves the address. So if I static_cast the given type to a void pointer to store it, and static_cast it back to a pointer of the original type, I shouldn't have any problems. Here is the relevant guts of the class:

```
template<class T>
T& get( const std::string& key ) 
{
    return *static_cast<T*>( _data[ key ] );   
}

template < typename T >
void put( const std::string& key, const T& val ) 
{
    T* typePointer = new T( val );       
    _data[ key ] = static_cast<void*>( typePointer );         
}

std::map< std::string, void* > _data;
```

For non-pointer arguments these methods all work fine and I wanted to see the put/get overhead compared to that of a static typed std::map. However, when inserting large numbers of objects into it, I would get "Access violation reading location" errors.

```
// this works
DynamicMap myMap1;    
for (uint i=0; i<100; i++) 
{
    myMap1.put( "mat"+i, MyClass() );
}

// this doesn't
DynamicMap myMap2;
for (uint i=0; i<100000; i++) 
{
    myMap2.put( "mat"+i, MyClass() );
}
```

It's been a few months since I've touched C++ so im a but rusty on VS2012's exceptions. I don't understand why this is occuring when inserting large numbers into the map... The number before it generates the exception changes between Debug mode and Release.

Comment: I guess `myMap1.set` would be `myMap1.put`, same for `myMap2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`warning: adding 'int' to a string does not append to the string`

Your `"mat"+i` does not create a new string with `i` appended at the end, so you end up messing up the keys. Use `"mat" + std::to_string(i)` (C++11), or

```
stringstream ss;
ss << i;
string i_string = ss.str();
myMap2.set( "mat"+i_string, MyClass() );
```